# Running Spark Aggregator sample

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to run the example from Spark 2.4.3 documentation found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator) on a Databricks cluster.

I've added missing methods and the code now looks like this:

```scala
case class Data(i: Int)

val customSummer =  new Aggregator[Data, Int, Int] {
 def zero: Int = 0
 def reduce(b: Int, a: Data): Int = b + a.i
 def merge(b1: Int, b2: Int): Int = b1 + b2
 def finish(r: Int): Int = r
 def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Int] = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.scalaInt
 def outputEncoder: Encoder[Int] = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.scalaInt
}.toColumn

val ds = Seq(Data(1)).toDS
val aggregated = ds.select(customSummer).collect
```

The error I'm getting is: `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable`

I found this in the stack trace: `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn`

[Here's the full stack trace](https://pastebin.com/1BKB7th4).

The question is, has someone been able to run similar code? If so, could you please point me to resources where I can learn what am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put the case class out side the testclass and make the outer class having the `Aggregator` Serializable.

```scala
class Test extends Serializable {
 @Test
  def test62805430(): Unit = {

    val customSummer =  new Aggregator[Data, Int, Int] {
      def zero: Int = 0
      def reduce(b: Int, a: Data): Int = b + a.i
      def merge(b1: Int, b2: Int): Int = b1 + b2
      def finish(r: Int): Int = r
      def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Int] = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.scalaInt
      def outputEncoder: Encoder[Int] = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.scalaInt
    }.toColumn

    val ds = Seq(Data(1)).toDS
    val aggregated = ds.select(customSummer).collect
    println(aggregated.mkString(",")) // 1
  }

}

case class Data(i: Int)
```